# Creating a 3d printable object using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

Looking to create a 3d printable container with perforated sides for airflow. The ideal design would be evenly spaced diamonds (not squares with sides parallel to the bottom). In 3d printing anything perfectly horizontal usually fails. Melted plastic responds to gravity and doesn't stay where you put it. If you print at a 45 degree angle the material below supports the new material as it's printed.

I could use a plane, and repeat knife project a bunch of times, then thickness modifier but I hoped for an easier way.

Can this be done with geometry nodes? Best would be if it responds to resizing by generating more, or less, geometry.

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a far easier manual method to accomplish this than using knife-project. Tesselate the sides of the container to the appropriate size faces. An option called "poke" for faces tesselates the square faces into four triangular polygons. Using specialized selection options you can select the vertical and horizontal edges and remove them. You're left with diamond shaped faces instead of square. Video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqcGJrOZLmc).